# jQuery Rails Dynamic Select Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, nested-attributes

I am following the railscast number 88 to create Dynamic Select Menus: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=asciicast

Essentially I am to have two drop down menus, one for State and one for City. The functionality is as such: upon selecting the State in the first drop-down menu, the City menu will dynamically change and only show the cities given the state that was selected ie. Select Minnesota for the State and in the City menu will show St. Paul, Minneapolis...etc. The user can then select the city given those results.

The models I am working with are:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :campaign_cities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :cities, through: :campaign_cities
end

class State < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :state

    has_many :campaign_cities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :campaigns, through: :campaign_cities
end

class CampaignCity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :campaign
end
```

Following the railscast outline, I have successfully been able to group the cities to their respective states (State menu on top, City menu on bottom):

[image]

but I have hit a wall on the jQuery part to allow for only showing the city that is in the selected state. Looking at the source code in my rails app, the collection selects for state and city I have setup as:

```
    <%= f.collection_select :id, State.order(:state), :id, :state %>

    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :city_ids, State.order(:state), :cities, :state, :id, :city %>
```

As for the html `<select id>`, looking at the page source, it is setting `campaign_id` for the state identifier:

[image]

and for the city, it's `<select id>` is `campaign_city_ids`:

[image]

Following the direction of the video, and inputting my ids, I came to the jQuery as:

```
jQuery ->
  cities = $('#campaign_city_ids').html()
  console.log(cities)
  $('#campaign_id').change ->
    state = $('#campaign_id :selected').text()
    options = $(cities).filter("optgroup[label=#{state}]").html()
    console.log(options)
    if options
      $('#campaign_city_ids').html(options)
    else
      $('#campaign_city_ids').empty();
```

But it does not allow the conditional menu structure to work, ie. Be able to select a State, say California, and the City menu automatically shows only the cities in California to then be selected.

How can I fix the jQuery code to make it work?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "extend the functionality as the condition dynamic drop-down should"?  What exactly happens vs what do you expect to happen?  Also, posting the console output from your log calls as well as the view code might help.

Comment: If you view the video at: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus-revised?view=asciicast you can see for his example that when selecting a country, only the states within that country will display. Fro my example, what I meant by "extend the functionality as the conditional dynamic drop-down should", is that when first selecting a state, then a city, in the city menu only those cities that are in that selected state will appear